# Naming conventions for function parameter variables?

Tags: php, parameters, function, naming-conventions

Is there a naming convention or maybe some guideline on how to name function parameters?

Since forever, I have been doing it like this:

```
function divide( $pDividend, $pDivisor )
{ ... }
```

That way I'll always know which variables were passed as parameters.

(This one's PHP, but it should be applicable to most programming languages)

Is there one major reason against this?

Is there a better way to do this or is it probably best to just avoid such naming schemes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If :

1. your functions/methods are well written and short (as they should be)
2. the variable names are descriptive enough

This practice is not needed.

If you need this, it means that the code written is not readable enough (functions/methods too long), cryptic variable/function names, bad OO practices, shortcuts, code debts, etc. :)

So it would be a signal that the code needs to be refactored/improved.

Comment: Haha, nice point of view on that topic. I'll definitely keep that in mind and see if that might be the reason for my naming convention!

Answer (score 2):

I think taking the advice of Code Complete regarding naming -anything- would be justified it's whole chapter 11 is on naming variables properly):

- Don't name it j, k, i, m, n (unless it's just for an iteration) or "placeholder" or "test". When the "test" works, I often don't take the time to rename the variable wherever it's been listed.
- Call it a **descriptive** name that's separate from the code's function ie "EmployeeComments" not "XMLEmp_Comment_File" because a lot of that information (XML, external file) could change, but that the program's working with "Employee Comments" won't
- Keep it as **broad and human readable** as possible so you're coding in English (or your language) not $j=$k/sqrt($pi); or something equally unintelligible.

As for parameters specifically, I've never used the P notation. I like the idea, but if you named them right wouldn't it be clear they were the parameters for the function?

Answer (score 1):

I've heard that some people will keep their function parameters one style, with the type of data a the first part of the variable (array = arr), and then capitalize the following words:

```
$arrFormData
```

where the rest of their variables are in a different style, where the words are all lower case, no type definition, and the words are separated by underscores.

```
$form_data
```

Personally, I tend to keep my variables the same as the rest of my variables, purely because on the first two lines of a function, I'm making sure that they are what I expect, or throwing an exception. After that, there shouldn't really be a difference between local variables and variables passed in. But, if it keeps your code clearer to type it one way, by all means.

Answer (score 1):

You should follow general guidelines for how to name parameters as you would for other variables (names should be clear, accurate, specific, consistent, and usually 8-20 characters long).

As for the prefix, I would recommend the opposite: leave the parameter unmarked, and mark anything that you do with the parameter in the function as a separate variable. For example:

```
function upperCase($title) {
    $upTitle = ucfirst($title);
    return $upTitle;
}
```

In my example, I use a bare parameter, `$title`. After I transform the input, I call it something else to indicate that it is now in a transformed state, `$upTitle`. That way I know that it is no longer just the function parameter. Merely calling your parameter `$pTitle` does not give you quite the same advantage as this consistent approach.

If you think about it, your method marks all the parameters on the interface, which is not the best level. If you look at the API of your program, all your function parameters are marked with `$p` meaning parameter, which is redundant. You are saying, all of my parameters are parameters, which we already know since they are part of the API. So I would recommend dropping the prefix for the parameter and instead using a series of semantic prefixes that denote what you have done to the parameter to transform it within the function, as in my example.

I disagree with the previous suggestion that you should just make your code more clear. Having clear code does not remove the need for having clear naming conventions.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to name variables (as you can see from the answers)

But as a general rule, they should be named such, that it is clear from just looking at the variable itself, what it does and what it is used for, right there and not have to go through thousands of lines of code to find out - and not just for who else might have to troubleshoot later but if your code is thousands of lines long for your own good if you yourself have to troubleshoot later

AND WHATEVER NAMING CONVENTIONS YOU CHOOSE BE CONSISTENT THROUGHOUT YOUR CODE - this cannot be iterated enough :)

Personally I use the following:
first part of the variable is for what it is
second part is for what it does/is used for
and for variables needed outside the function, class, etc. the third part is for the function, class, etc. it comes from

Ex:
I want to name the variable for a video thumbnail on the front page:
so i start with what it is (lower_case) - thumbnail
then I add on what it is used for (first letter upper_case) - Video
and since I need it on the front page outside the function I finish off with the function it came from (seperated by under_score) - getVideoAll

Giving me $thumbnailVideo_getVideoAll

That way no matter where I look at the variable in any part of the code (HTML, PHP, etc.) I know...
ah this is the thumbnail for the video I'm trying to show and if it for some reason doesn't work I firstly don't need to go anywhere to spell-check and secondly I know exactly what function, class it was called for (getVideoAll) and can just go there to troubleshoot

If I instead just had named it $tnVid I might personally have a vague notion of what it is but someone else looking at will have no idea that tn stands for (t)humb(n)ail, etc.
so to troubleshoot they would have to first look at the surrounding code to maybe infer that it is probable a variable for a thumbnail and second go through thousands of lines of code to find what function, class, etc. it came from - and that's hours of work just finding what you need to even start troubleshooting - instead of the 5 seconds it takes seeing $thumbnailVideo_getVideoAll and going -
 ah this is the thumbnail for the video and I need to go  to the function getVideoAll to troubleshoot

Answer (score 0):

I have naming conventions for some variables, like member fields or static fields, because the declaration of the variable may be far away from the code where I use it.  For parameters or local variables I do not use anything, as usually the variable definition is about ten lines away.

Especially in the all IDE camp people seem to get more and more to dislike any prefix or suffix, as "the IDE provides highlighting".   Well, it doesn't help me, and I dislike having semantic information only available as color.  However, I can see there point, as the variable name should make the most important information clear, and if it doesn't, nothing helps.

So, this is more about style.  Good naming is more important than good prefixes.  For the schemes: pick one, stick to it.  This will help the poor maintenance developer.  Yes, those are the people who usually also prefer { } around single statement blocks and so on, but it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The greatest chance for confusion for me is in member functions.  If possible, I like to see differences in naming between:

- local variables: `index`
- class member variables: `m_index`
- class static variables: `ClassIndex`
- global variables: `INDEX`

This can make it easier to track down what's happening where.  However, I agree with Toto that it's best to make your functions short enough so that these conventions don't make or break your ability to figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the [PHP Coding Standards](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/php-7.0.0RC1/CODING_STANDARDS) or [Coding standard for php](https://gist.github.com/mrabbani/2abdeafa7ee3dc48f9f1) which is suggested to contribute in core php.

Answer (score 0):

So after looking at all this, I decided to go with:

`ClassName
methodName
propertyName
function_name (meant for global functions)
$variable_name`